# Json GET is not showing the details in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to show the details of each Student with Json and I think it is not going to the `ajax` part.

It shows the `id` and the `url` when I `console.log()` them, but I get this error message for the ajax part

[image: Error image]

I don't know what's missing or where is the issue?

This is my **html link**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "StudentDetails", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "modalDetails", @id = item.ID  })
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".modalDetails").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();         //stop the default action upon click

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            console.log(url);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: id },
                dataType: "json",
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".modalDetails").append('<span> First Name: ' + data.firstName + '</span></br>');
                    console.log("success");
                }                
            });

            $('#myModal').modal('show');        // show the modal pop up    
        });
    });
</script>
```

**StudentController**

```
public JsonResult StudentDetails(int id)
        {
            Student student = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);

            var json = new{
                firstName = student.FirstMidName
            };

            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: shouldn't your url be like this http://localhost:52245/Student/StudentDetails/?id=23 not like this http://localhost:52245/Student/StudentDetails/23?id=23.

Answer (score 1):

Everything was fine, except that I needed to build the solution and `append` the details to the `modal-body`. Sometimes it is just a simple fix.